# Magento Parameter not adopt when use mod_rewrite

Tags: https, htaccess, parameter

first of all I have to say that this looks for me like a very complex problem. I just tried about 30 variants and solutions I found, none of them works perfect.

I have a Magento 1.8.1.0. Community shop running on a managed Server with a SSL certificate, the certificate only runs on the "www" Domain. Of course I wanna use the whole page with "http**s**:// www.domain.com", that runs very well. Also I have no problem when I´m on a page and change the URL to "http:// www.domain.com", "http:// domain.com or "http**s**:// domain.com" on a normal article, the url redirect perfectly to "http**s**:// www.domain.com".

So, let´s take a look at the problem, the "?" parameters. When I change an url from "http**s**:// www.domain.com/category/article.html?manufacturer=42" to "http:// www.domain.com/category/article.html?manufacturer=42"  the url change to "http**s**:// www.domain.com/category/article.html". As you see, the "?manufacturer=42" get lost.

here is our very complex .htaccess:

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    #SSLOptions StdEnvVars
    #SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    #SSLRequireSSL
    #SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "sample-domain.com"
    #ErrorDocument 403 https://www.sample-domain.com

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.finkeisen-sonnenschutz\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sample-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTPS/
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.sample-domain.com/ [R=301,L]



############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

# Enable expirations

ExpiresActive On

# Default directive

ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# My favicon

ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year?

# Images

ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

# CSS

ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7 days"

# Javascript

ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 7 days"


</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

#php_flag display_errors on
#SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true
```

Do you have an idea what we could try to solve the problem?
I also use the URL-rewrite in the magento backend, maybe that could be a part of the problem

Answer (score 2):

This rewrite has nothing to do with `.htaccess`, because magento is doing this.

But you can try to add

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Maybe you want to omit the `?`

Comment: Thank you Fabian for the tipp, but sadly that doesn´t solve the problem. It looks like nothing changed at all. What you mean with omit the "?"? I thougt magento need this for search filters, or is there an alternative?

Comment: Maybe ? is included in QUERY_STRING.